# Add overlay but output has wrong audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, overlay

```
ffmpeg -i Knight.mp4 -i "4h.mp4" -filter_complex "scale=854:480 [v1]; [1:v][v1]overlay=20:20" output.mp4
```

But `output.mp4` not have `Knight.mp4` audio.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [amerge filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i Knight.mp4 -i 4h.mp4 -filter_complex
    "[0:v]scale=854:480[v1];[1:v][v1]overlay=20:20[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge[a]"
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

Comment: i want output.mp4 have two audio  from Knight.mp4 and 4h.mp4 .